# [Python]How to sort a string with two variables?

Tags: python, sorting, variables

Hello I am somewhat new to python so please bear with me.

My python program has the following lines:

print "Player 1: " +str(player1points)

print "Player 2: " +str(player2points)

print "Player 3: " +str(player3points)

print "Player 4: " +str(player4points)

The player#points are what my program has calculated it to be, so differs everytime I run it.

The result would yield:

Player 1: 3

Player 2: 4

Player 3: 3

Player 4: 5

If possible, I want to sort the result so that each player's points is ranked from highest to lowest first, then the player.  If two players are tied for points, then the player with the lowest number will be listed first.

So I expect my results to be like:

Player 4: 5

Player 2: 4

Player 1: 3

Player 3: 3

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You need to tell us what have you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Can you sort them before they become one string, ie. when you have the scores and the player id's separately?

Comment: How are these players represented in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the examples of

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Operator_Module_Functions

Answer (score 1):

If you already have player objects or dictionaries, you could sort with:

```
players.sort(key=lambda player: player.score, reverse=True)
```

If not, process your array and split at each ':'

Sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    "entry point"
    player_strings = ['Player 1:3', 'Player 2:4', 'Player 3:3', 'Player 4:5']
    players = []
    for player_string in player_strings:
        name, score = player_string.split(':')
        players.append({'name':name, 'score':score})
    players.sort(key=lambda player: int(player['score']), reverse=True)
    for player in players:
        print ('%s has a score of %s' % (player['name'], player['score']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(values, key=lambda s: s.split(': ')[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a "key function" to the list.sort method allows you to customize how it is sorted.

```
def sort_players(players):
    r"""Sort the players by points.

    >>> print sort_players('Player 1: 3\n'
    ...                    '\n'
    ...                    'Player 2: 4\n'
    ...                    '\n'
    ...                    'Player 3: 3\n'
    ...                    '\n'
    ...                    'Player 4: 5\n')
    Player 4: 5
    Player 2: 4
    Player 1: 3
    Player 3: 3
    """
    # split into a list
    players = players.split("\n")

    # filter out empty lines
    players = [player for player in players if player != '']

    def points(player_report):
        """Parse the number of points won by a player from a player report.

        A "player report" is a string like 'Player 2: 6'.
        """
        import re
        # Match the last string of digits in the passed report
        points = re.search(r'\d+$', player_report).group()
        return int(points)

    # Pass `points` as a "key function".
    # The list will be sorted based on the values it returns.
    players.sort(key=points, reverse=True)

    # Make the sorted list back into a string.
    return "\n".join(players)
```

Comment: This answer was really helpful! However for my program I have it set as "Player 1:" +str(player1points), instead of just "Player 1: 3"  Where player1points is assigned to whatever the program calculates it to be.  How will I go about to using this function to accept my string?

Comment: @Bob Loin: Not sure if I understand you.  The regular expression used by the `points` function will find the last string of digits (`\d+`) in a given "player report".  I'm using the term "player report" to refer to a string like `Player 2: 6`.  So as long as your `player1points` is a positive integer at the end of the report string, `points` will return it as an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total newbie when it comes to this.

Comment: When I type this into my program: print "Player 1: " +str(player1points), it will give me the following result: Player 1: 1.  However, when I input: sort_players('Player 1: +str(player1points)\n'), it gives me error: AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

Comment: @Bob Loin: Wait.. you're literally typing `sort_players('Player 1: +str(player1points)\n')`?  So then the last character in the first (and only) player report line is `)`.  If the last character of a player report is any non-digit, you'll get that error message, because `points` expects the report to end with an integer.  It's not particularly robust, but making it robust is a bit more complicated.

Comment: So any chance of correcting the function? or how should I go about correcting my input.

Comment: @Bob Loin: The function, as written, works on the input you gave in your original question.  This is shown in the [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) for `sort_players`.  If you're having trouble producing input in that format, you should ask another question, or at least edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the 'players reports' are in a list:

```
values = ['Player 1: 3','Player 2: 4','Player 3: 3','Player 4: 5']

values.sort(key=lambda s: [(-int(b),a) for a,b in (s.split(':'),)])

print values
```

results in

```
['Player 4: 5', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 1: 3', 'Player 3: 3']
```

=============

Bob Loin said he wants to obtain

> Player **4**: 5, Player **2**: 4, Player **1**: 3, Player **3**: 3

Daniel's Roseman works well or not depending on the treated list.

My solution gives the right result. See the difference on the second list

```
values = ['Player 1: 3','Player 2: 4','Player 3: 3','Player 4: 5']

print '   ',values
print
print 'Dan',sorted(values, key=lambda s: s.split(': ')[1], reverse=True)
print 'eyq',sorted(values, key=lambda s: [(-int(b),a) 
                                          for a,b in (s.split(':'),)])

print '\n===================================\n'

values = ['Player 3: 3','Player 2: 4','Player 1: 3','Player 4: 5']

print '   ',values
print
print 'Dan',sorted(values, key=lambda s: s.split(':')[1], reverse=True)
print 'eyq',sorted(values, key=lambda s: [(-int(b),a) 
                                          for a,b in (s.split(': '),)])
```

result

```
    ['Player 1: 3', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 3: 3', 'Player 4: 5']

Dan ['Player 4: 5', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 1: 3', 'Player 3: 3']
eyq ['Player 4: 5', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 1: 3', 'Player 3: 3']

===================================

    ['Player 3: 3', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 1: 3', 'Player 4: 5']

Dan ['Player 4: 5', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 3: 3', 'Player 1: 3']
eyq ['Player 4: 5', 'Player 2: 4', 'Player 1: 3', 'Player 3: 3']
```